# Datadog distinct count on top list metric

Tags: logging, metrics, datadog

Having a top list widget in datadog dashboard, I want to count all the unique account that have status Live, the status can be changed multiple times in a day and i want to count all the accounts with status Live but taking in mind only the latest log. Here is my query

```
"sum:${datadog_logs_metric.accounts.name}{*} by {status}.as_count()"
```

How to select only distinct accounts having in mind the accountId

Current behavior now, if I have 3 logs(Live, Away,Live) for the same account it will be included twice in the sum of accounts with status: Live instead of once.